# jquery DataTables sort numeric an div content with title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting, datatables, jquery-ui-sortable

Hy guys,

I use this code to sorting natural an column:

```
-2
-1
0
1
2



    function naturalSort(a, b) {
    var re = /(^-?[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]*)[df]?e?[0-9]?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$|[0-9]+)/gi,
        sre = /(^[ ]*|[ ]*$)/g,
        dre = /(^([\w ]+,?[\w ]+)?[\w ]+,?[\w ]+\d+:\d+(:\d+)?[\w ]?|^\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}|^\w+, \w+ \d+, \d{4})/,
        hre = /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,
        ore = /^0/,
    // convert all to strings and trim()
        x = a.toString().replace(sre, '') || '',
        y = b.toString().replace(sre, '') || '',
    // chunk/tokenize
        xN = x.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/, '').replace(/^\0/, '').split('\0'),
        yN = y.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/, '').replace(/^\0/, '').split('\0'),
    // numeric, hex or date detection
        xD = parseInt(x.match(hre)) || (xN.length != 1 && x.match(dre) && Date.parse(x)),
        yD = parseInt(y.match(hre)) || xD && y.match(dre) && Date.parse(y) || null;
    // first try and sort Hex codes or Dates
    if (yD) if (xD < yD) return -1;
    else if (xD > yD) return 1;
    // natural sorting through split numeric strings and default strings
    for (var cLoc = 0, numS = Math.max(xN.length, yN.length); cLoc < numS; cLoc++) {
        // find floats not starting with '0', string or 0 if not defined (Clint Priest)
        oFxNcL = !(xN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc] || 0;
        oFyNcL = !(yN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc] || 0;
        // handle numeric vs string comparison - number < string - (Kyle Adams)
        if (isNaN(oFxNcL) !== isNaN(oFyNcL)) return (isNaN(oFxNcL)) ? 1 : -1;
        // rely on string comparison if different types - i.e. '02' < 2 != '02' < '2'
        else if (typeof oFxNcL !== typeof oFyNcL) {
            oFxNcL += '';
            oFyNcL += '';
        }
        if (oFxNcL < oFyNcL) return -1;
        if (oFxNcL > oFyNcL) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
};
// Natural Sorting
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-asc'] = function (a, b) {
    return naturalSort(a, b);
};
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    return naturalSort(a, b) * -1;
};
```

It works fine, but if I put an div with title as an content before the number, it does not work correctly:

```
<div title='juhu'>-1</div >
<div title='juhu'>-2</div >
<div title='juhu'>0</div >
<div title='juhu'>1</div >
<div title='juhu'>2</div >
```

Does anyone has an solution for this problem?

Comment: Javascript should remove the div and pick just the number...

Answer (score 0):

It helps to use console.log in your Javascript.  If you log the xN and yN numbers, you'll see  positive numbers look like this: `<div title="juhu">,1,</div>` but negative numbers look like this `<div title="juhu">-,2,</div>`.

As you iterate through the tokenized string, when you compare positive to negative numbers, the first comparison will compare `<div title="juhu">` with `<div title="juhu">-`.  It will compare them as pure ASCII, and so in "asciibetical" order, `<div title="juhu">` is less than `<div title="juhu">-`.

Add this at the top of your naturalSort function:

```
function naturalSort(a, b) {
 a = typeof a.replace == 'function' ?
        a.replace( /<[\s\S]*?>/g, "" ) : a;
    b = typeof a.replace == 'function' ?
        b.replace( /<[\s\S]*?>/g, "" ) : b;
```

That will strip out the HTML tags, and should solve your problem.

DataTables is excellent and often will have what you need built in.  Look at this page, it may help: http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/type-detection

The code I used above came from the "Numbers with HTML" section.